# "Call to undefined function Mpdf\mb_regex_encoding()" while mbstring is enabled

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf, mbstring

I have **mbstring** enabled in php.ini ("php -m" in CMD shows mbstring in the list), but I'm still getting this error.

[Requirements page](https://mpdf.github.io/about-mpdf/requirements-v7.html) for mPDF says that it should include **mbregex** as well. I don't know, maybe it's missing. How can I install it? Or it is not the problem?

My PHP version is 7.4.19.

UPDATE:
I'm using MAMP as my local server. phpInfo says current configuration has both mbstring and mbregex.

Comment: Looks more like a namespace issue. Look for the command and put a slash in front of it. `\mb_regex_encoding()`

Comment: @aynber it's in Mpdf.php file. Should I edit it?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: No, you should not edit this file. In general you should never edit files inside of `vendor` directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined function Mpdf\mb\_regex\_encoding()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951700/call-to-undefined-function-mpdf-mb-regex-encoding)

Comment: @rob006 Nope. I have mbstring installed and still getting this error. I said that in my question, by the way.

Comment: You may have it installed in the console but not for web. Run phpinfo() in some web file.

Comment: I'm using MAMP for my local server and mbstring (and mbregex) are also enabled in phpInfo

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully reproduced this behaviour with MAMP.

Everything runs correctly with official windows PHP builds from php.net, so I believe there is an error in MAMP PHP build, even though everything in phpinfo seems OK.

Try submitting a bug report with MAMP.